# How do I perform additional database queries when serializing a value with Serde?

Tags: rust, serde

A `Program` has a one-to-many relationship with `Project`. I'm looking for an ideal way to include all the projects in a program when I print the JSON response.

```
extern crate rocket_contrib;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_json;

use rocket_contrib::Json;
use serde_json::Value;

mod schema {
    table! {
        projects (id) {
            id -> Int4,
            title -> Varchar,
            program_id -> Int4,
            is_archived -> Bool,
        }
    }

    table! {
        programs (id) {
            id -> Int4,
            title -> Varchar,
            is_archived -> Bool,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let program = Program::get(id);
    let json_value = Json(json!({ "result": program }));
}
```

I looked into implementing custom serializing:

```
impl Serialize for Program {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
    }
}
```

But I do not have the `db::Conn` required to pull the projects in this function.

I'm looking for a response like:

```
{ 
    "id": 1,
    "is_archived": false,
    "title": "Program 1",
    "projects": [{
      "id": 2,
      "is_archived": false,
       "title": "Project 1"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I think you need to define a struct `ProgramWithProjects` or similar, representing the desired structure, including a field `projects: Vec<Project>`.  You can fill the struct while you hold the database connection, and then serialize it to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The practical answer is **don't**. Serialization of a value should not involve arbitrary database calls, it should *only serialize*. Create a struct to hold all the data:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct ProgramAndProjects {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    program: Program,
    projects: Vec<Project>,
}
```

Then write a function that populates that struct by doing the required database queries and directly serialize the result.

This has a huge benefit of being wildly more testable, as well.

---

That being said, it is *possible* to do, but it's likely not worth it. You can stick a database connection *into* `Program` (or create a newtype with the connection and the `Program`) and then make use of the connection during serialization.

See also:

- [How can I get Serde to allocate strings from an arena?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51988630/155423)